# adjoint transformation intuition

Tags: inner-products, adjoint-operators, dual-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

I can't find the connection between the Riesz Representation Theorem and inner product spaces and the adjoint transformation. 
what I understood that dual spaces enables us to have an transpose operator, but I can't understand why the the adjoint operator is "adjoint" and the connection with conjugate part in the inner product complex field.
how can I also develop an intuition about how the adjoint operator behaves with inner product space over field C or R?
can someone please help me connect the dots and develop an intuition about how the adjoint behaves? (in the context go finite spaces)
thank you

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of adjoint in the context of finite vector spaces?

Comment: I am familiar with the formal definition, but I am trying to understand its underlying intuition. @Phicar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's start with the transpose operator. The transpose can be defined **without reference to an inner product** and only requires the vector space structure. The way to think about the tranpose is that it turns a linear map $f$ from $V$ to $W$ into a linear map $f^T$ from $W^*$ to $V^*$, and it does this in the most "natural" way possible.

If words, if we are trying to define a map from $W^*$ to $V^*$ we start with a function $g \in W^*$ and we want to turn this into a function that acts on vectors in $V$ and returns a real number. Well we know that $g$ can act on vectors in $W$ and we know that using $f$ we can turn vectors in $V$ into vectors in $W$ and chaining these together gives us a way to let $g$ act on vectors in $V$!

In symbols, what we just did above is define $f^T(g)(v) = g(f(v))$. We first use $f$ to map $v$ from a vector in $V$ to a vector in $W$ and then we use our element $g \in W^*$ to map it to a real number.

Now the Hermitian adjoint operator is a way of turning a function $f: V \to W$ into a function $f^*: W \to V$. The best way of thinking about this operator is through the transpose. The transpose gives us an operator $f^T: W^* \to V^*$. To turn this into a map from $W$ to $V$, we need to fix isomorphisms between $W$ and $W^*$ and $V$ and $V^*$. To map a vector $w$ from $W$ to $V$, you use the isomorphism between $W$ and $W^*$ to map $w$ to $w' \in W^*$, then you use the tranpose to map it to a vector $v' \in V^*$ and then you use the isomorphism between $V$ and $V'$ to map it to a vector $v \in V$.

You could describe the above construction with the following diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
W^* @>{f^T}>> V^*\\
@VV{\cong}V @VV{\cong}V\\
W @>{f^*}>> V
\end{CD}

Now the connection with inner product spaces and the Riesz Representation Theorem is that an inner product on a vector space $V$ gives you a "natural" way to define an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$.

For every vector $v \in V$, we can define the map $\varphi_v: V \to K$ (where $K$ is the base field) by $\varphi_v(\cdot) = \langle \cdot,v \rangle$. By the linearity of the inner product, $\varphi_v$ is an element of the dual space $V^*$. In addition the map from $V$ to $V^*$ given by $v \to \varphi_v$ is (anti)-linear and by the non-degeneracy of the inner product, it is injective. The Riesz Representation Theorem says that this injection is also a surjection and therefore a bijection. This means that whenever we have an inner product we can define $\varphi_v$ for every $v \in V$ and the map sending $v$ to $\varphi_v$ is a bijection between $V$ and $V^*$.

Now putting these two concepts together (the tranpose and the connection between inner product spaces and dual spaces), we can define the transpose $f^T$ without the inner product structure as a map from $W^* \to V^*$. The inner product structure gives us isomorphisms between $V$ and $V^*$ and $W$ and $W^*$, and chaining these isomorphisms together with the tranpose we can get a Hermitian adjoint map $f^*$ which maps $W$ to $V$.

EDIT: Added connection with $\mathbb{C}$.

Whenever we start writing linear transformations as matrices we first have to fix a basis. This also gives an alternate way of defining an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$ (search for "dual basis") and it is a useful exercise to verify that these two isomorphisms between $V$ and $V^*$ agree if and only if the basis that you started with is orthonormal when the base field is $\mathbb{R}$. In this case, let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be an orthonormal basis for $V$ and let $v^1,\ldots,v^n$ be its dual basis. Similarly, let $w_1,\ldots,w_m$ be an orthonormal basis for $W$ and let $w^1,\ldots,w^n$ be its dual basis.

Now if we let the matrix representation of $f$ be

$$\begin{bmatrix} f_{11} & \ldots & f_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
f_{m1} & \ldots & f_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}$$

then we have $f(v_i) = \sum_j f_{ji} w_j$. Now if we consider the transpose we have

$$f^T(w^i)(v_k) = w^i(f(v_k)) = w^i\left( \sum_j f_{jk} w^j \right) = f_{ik} = \left( \sum_j f_{ij} v^j \right)(v_k)$$

so

$$f^T(w^i) = \sum_j f_{ij} v^j$$

so the matrix representation of $f^T$ is exactly the traditional transpose of the matrix representation of $f$.

Now let us consider the adjoint in the case of $K = \mathbb{C}$. In this case we have that the map from $v$ to $\varphi_v$ is anti-linear.

Let $w = \sum_i c_i w_i$. Then $\varphi_w = \sum_i \overline{c_i} w^i$. Now if we apply $f^T$ to this we get

$$f^T(\varphi_w) = f^T\left(\sum_i \overline{c_i} w^i\right) = \sum_j  \left(\sum_i \overline{c_i}f_{ij}\right) v^j$$

Finally, when we apply the anti-linear isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$ we get that

$$ f^*(w) = \left(\sum_i c_i\overline{f_{ij}}\right) v^j $$

so the matrix representation of $f^*$ is

$$\begin{bmatrix} \overline{f_{11}} & \ldots & \overline{f_{1m}} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\overline{f_{n1}} & \ldots & \overline{f_{nm}}
\end{bmatrix}$$

which is the conjugate transpose. The basic intuition is that the isomorphism between $W$ and $W^*$ conjugates all of the coefficients of $w$, then this is fed through the transposed matrix $f^T$ and then all of the coefficients are conjugated once again which flips the coefficients of $w$ back and conjugates the coordinates of $f^T$.

EDIT 2: For completeness, I figured I would add why the adjoint as I defined it above is equivalent to the traditional definition of the adjoint as the unique operator $f^*$ such that for all $v,w$ we have

$$\langle f(v), w \rangle = \langle v, f^*(w) \rangle.$$

If you look at the commutative diagram above, we will start with an element $w \in W$ in the bottom left and trace it using the two paths to the top right. First, we can go right to $f^*(w) \in V$. Then we can use the isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$ to go up to $\varphi_{f^*(w)}$.

Alternatively, we could first go up using the isomorphism between $W$ and $W^*$ to get to $\varphi_w$ and then move right to get to $f^T(\varphi_w)$ so we have that

$$ f^T(\varphi_w) = \varphi_{f^*(w)} $$

as elements of $V^*$. Now evaluating both sides on $v \in V$ gives

$$ \langle f(v), w \rangle =  \varphi_w(f(v)) = f^T(\varphi_w)(v) = \varphi_{f^*(w)}(v) = \langle v, f^*(w) \rangle $$

as desired.

Comment: thanks, the picture is much clearer now. but the remaining thing that I haden't figured out is the adjoint on complex field and why we have conjugate part.

Comment: I just added a discussion of the connection with $\mathbb{C}$ in my response.

Comment: there just one thing that is not obvious to me. " what we just did above is define ()()=(()) ". here did we define ()() to be equal to (()), or its not a definition. if not a definition its not clear to me why they are equal, because the are not the same linear functional, so they could map v differently. thank you

Comment: @MohammedQaiss This is the definition of $f^T$. The text above is describing the intuition behind this definition. We are given a map $f: V \to W$ and we want to get a map $W^* \to V^*$, which means that when we are given a function $W  \to K$ we need to find a function $V \to K$. You can think of this as being given a function $W \to K$ and a vector in $V$ and finding a way for the function to act on the vector. The obvious way to do that is to first map the vector from $V$ to $W$ using $f$ (since $f: V \to W$) and then to apply the function mapping $W \to K$.

Comment: What is all this stuff for? Will all this be useful in functional analysis? or representation theory? or topology? I am curious.